# Find the general solution of this differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried my best but i couldn't find a solution to this equation

$yy' = \frac{x^2+1}{y-1}$

I got to this solution but I don't know what to do after it

$ \frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^3}{3}+x+c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly computed the general solutions. It's not always necessary to write $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to so hard to solve that 3rd degree equation that I lost hope. Thank you so much